# Does anyone have the SharePoint Server 2010 Prerequisites in a Zip file?

Tags: sharepoint-server, prerequisites

I want to install SharePoint Server 2010.  The problem is, some of the sites from which the "prerequisites" were once available have closed down.

For instance, TechNet and MSDN are no longer running.

Does anyone have the SharePoint Prerequisites in a Zip file?

Please let me know.

Comment: It's actual question? You still need SP2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoSPSourceBuilder](https://github.com/brianlala/AutoSPSourceBuilder) powershell module to achieve that.
Or just open its [source file](https://github.com/brianlala/AutoSPSourceBuilder/blob/master/Scripts/AutoSPSourceBuilder.xml) and copy all direct links that relevant to SP2010 (rows 8-22).